# Issue with Yum update Redhat Linux Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, aws, amazon-ec2

In my scenario , for some reason yum has stopped working in my Amazon EC2 instance, located in the us east -1 region. There seems to be something wrong with the path of the repo metadata, is this correct? Is this a version issue , I found this problem after I upgrade the awe cli version 2. I would be very grateful for any help to rectify the issue?

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

    sudo yum update -y
    Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
    
    
    Could not contact any CDS load balancers: https://rhui.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/content/.

yum repolist
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Repo rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7 forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt
 
Could not contact any CDS load balancers: https://rhui.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/content/.

rpm -qa rh-amazon-rhui-client
rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.118-1.el7.noarch
```